# From raw SQL to Laravel Eloquent or query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I've used a slow Eloquent query and I changed it to faster one but with raw SQL

There is GroupBy used in the later part of code and now it fails.

```
$app_visits = DB::select(DB::raw('select id, place from table where 1=1'));     
$app_visits = $app_visits->groupBy('place');
```

is there an easy way to use similar method with the raw table I'm getting?

Comment: Well, you can add the `GROUP BY place` to your original query, and you don't need `where 1=1`. Without the error, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just also use in the raw query the groupby?

```
$app_visits = DB::select(DB::raw('select id, place from table where 1=1 GROUP BY place'));
```